# Unbake from keyframes

Tags: keyframes, baking, rigid-body-simulation

I am experimenting with rigid body simulations and have an animated cube hitting a stack of cubes and moving around. The problem is, I tried to render and forgot to bake to keyframes, but now that I have, the keyframes are still not rendering and I can't see them in the timeline. I tried recreating the blend file using the properties panel and frame guessing but now the objects are not colliding! Is there a way to revert back to rigid body after keyframes are baked?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.